# Inequality of scalar-product and norm

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Why does the following inequality hold, given $A$ is symmetric and $\lambda_{\min} (A)$ is the smallest Eigenvalue of $A$?
$$v^\top A v \ge \lambda_{\min} (A) \; ||v||^2$$

Comment: I don't understand why people would up vote a standard Linear Algebra question when the OP showed no attempt at the question... or why people dish out full solution to these...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $A$ is real and symmetric, it can be orthogonally diagonalized, that is, for some orthogonal $U$ (meaning $U^TU=I$) we have $U^T A U = \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal whose entries are the eigenvalues of $A$. Since $A$ is real and symmetric, its eigenvalues are all real.

Note that since $U$ is orthogonal, we have $\|Ux\|= \|x\|$.

Then $\langle v , A v \rangle = \langle v , U^T \Lambda U v \rangle = \langle U v , \Lambda U v \rangle = \sum \limits_{k} \lambda_k [Uv]_k^2 \ge \lambda_\min \sum \limits_{k}  [Uv]_k^2 = \lambda_\min \|U v\|^2 = \lambda_\min \|u\|^2$.

Comment: Thanks, copper.hat! I missed the fact that a symmetric matrix can be unitarily diagonalized.